# tikz picture inside beamer frame

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I was trying to put [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/red-black-tree/) code from `tikz` official page into a `beamer`'s `frame` and got this error:

```
/home/.../file.tex:100: Illegal parameter number in definition of \test.
<to be read again> 
               1
l.100 \end{tikzpicture}`
```

But if I put this outside the `frame` it compiles and makes a new frame with this picture inside it but with some absolutely wrong pending (this picture is in the top-left corner of the `frame`)

How can I put this image inside the `frame` with a proper aligment (just like the one which does the text have when I put it in `frame`)

For example:

```
% Red-black tree
% Author: Madit
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, text centered,
    font=\sffamily},
  arn_n/.style = {treenode, circle, white, font=\sffamily\bfseries,     draw=black,
    fill=black, text width=1.5em},% arbre rouge noir, noeud noir
  arn_r/.style = {treenode, circle, red, draw=red, 
    text width=1.5em, very thick},% arbre rouge noir, noeud rouge
  arn_x/.style = {treenode, rectangle, draw=black,
    minimum width=0.5em, minimum height=0.5em}% arbre rouge noir, nil
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance =     5cm/#1,
  level distance = 1.5cm}] 
\node [arn_n] {33}
    child{ node [arn_r] {15} 
            child{ node [arn_n] {10} 
                child{ node [arn_r] {5} edge from parent node[above     left]
                         {$x$}} %for a named pointer
                            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }
            child{ node [arn_n] {20}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {18}}
                            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }                            
    }
    child{ node [arn_r] {47}
            child{ node [arn_n] {38} 
                            child{ node [arn_r] {36}}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {39}}
            }
            child{ node [arn_n] {51}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {49}}
                            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }
        }
; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This code give's an error I descripted above. If I delete lines

```
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}
```

It will work but not with a proper aligment. And if I delete

```
[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1, level distance = 1.5cm}]
```

in

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1, level distance = 1.5cm}]
```

It will also compile with no styling but inside a frame with a proper aligment

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks for your tip! I've updated my question with some code

Comment: Use `\begin{frame}[fragile]`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this worked, thanks a lot! Please, could you write this as an answer and I'm going to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\begin{frame}[fragile]....`