# How to adjust text inside tikzpicture in beamer slide? (MWE available)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles

The following simple code gives almost what I need. But I need it inside a slide in beamer. So when I remove the two commented lines of `frame` to make a slide, the output is somehow disturbed. Can someone fix it (and possibly provide some intuition)?
Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,matrix}
\begin{document}
%\begin{frame}
    

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{bigbox} = [minimum size=3cm,draw=blue!50, thick, fill=blue!10, rounded corners, rectangle]
\tikzstyle{box} = [minimum size=1.5cm, rounded corners,rectangle, fill=blue!50]


\matrix[row sep=20mm, column sep=15mm, inner sep=7mm, bigbox, matrix of nodes, every node/.style=box] {
1 & 2 \\
};

\node (h1) [yshift=12mm] {Texta};

\node (h2) [bigbox,xshift=6cm] {Textb};

\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
```

[image]

[tikz picture inside beamer frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246494/tikz-picture-inside-beamer-frame)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{bigbox} = [minimum size=3cm,draw=blue!50, thick, fill=blue!10, rounded corners, rectangle]
\tikzstyle{box} = [minimum size=1.5cm, rounded corners,rectangle, fill=blue!50]


\matrix[row sep=20mm, column sep=15mm, inner sep=7mm, bigbox, matrix of nodes, every node/.style=box] {
1 & 2 \\
};

\node (h1) [yshift=12mm] {Texta};

\node (h2) [bigbox,xshift=6cm] {Textb};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And if you want to move contents up

use

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    
\vspace{-3cm}%<--------------------------------add appropriate dimension
\begin{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a top aligned frame \begin{frame}[fragile,t] instead of a vspace command in the second example?

Comment: of course --never knew the t option existed --still learning